# SiriKit intents not working with localization

Tags: xcode, localization, sirikit

I've implemented some of the Lists and Notes domain of SiriKit. It works as desired in my base language, English. Now I'm trying to localize that part of the app and test it.

In the simplest test that I can create, I'm trying to run the `INSearchForNotebookItemsIntent` in Spanish. On the documentation for this intent, "Enséñame todas mis notas en *appName*" is listed as an equivalent for "Show me all my notes on *appName*". The English form runs fine with my Intents and IntentsUI extensions, that is, my extensions are launched and produce the expected results.

So I changed my device's language to Spanish. I changed Siri to Spanish. I edited the scheme in XCode to the language Spanish and region Spain, and I set the Siri Intent Query to *Enséñame todas mis notas en My App*. Of course "My App" was the real app being tested.

All built and launched Siri fine, but Siri responds with, "Ojalá pudiera, pero My App todavia no me deja hacer eso." ("I'm sorry, but My App still will not let me do that.") And my intents extension is not launched, so it's not a failure response from my code.

Any suggestions on what to do differently to test localized implementations of SiriKit intents? I'm not sure how to get Spanish Siri to even recognize that My App can entertain the query.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet. I've posted it, reported it, etc, and no word on whether it's messed up or I'm messed up.

Comment: Okay... I was able to figure out some almost working sentences in German (Siri still will ask for the name of the list though it's in the sentence), but it's a very tedious process as it's undocumented. The example sentence Apple provides in their docs don't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

- Delete any existing shortcuts created in a different language
- Change device and Siri language as you described
- After changing Siri language, restart your device. I found Siri does
  not pick up the new language properly unless this is done.
- Create a new shortcut in the new language

The shortcut should now work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The two new parts were to restart the device, so I did that this time, and to delete existing shortcuts, so I did that this time even though Siri Shortcuts are not the issue at hand. The difficulty is getting Siri/iOS to recognize that the app supports a standard Intent Domain (not Shortcuts/custom intents). Despite these changes, Siri responded in the same way, not recognizing support for intent domains in Spanish that it does in English.